# Firefox extension to modify about:config preferences

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

In Firefox I keep getting the pop-up which says "A script on this page may be busy, or may have stopped responding...".  I discovered that I can prevent this by browsing to about:config  and increasing the preference for dom.max_script_run_time from 10 to 30 seconds.  I would like to be able to propagate this preference for others who are not quite tech savvy, so I was wondering if there is a way I can automate this change, maybe through a Firefox extension?  I've never made one, so I'm not really sure where to start.

Comment: The correct way to fix this would be to fix the script, not the timeout length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although i agree that the best solution for this would be to fix the script that is giving you problems, you might not control that, so here's how you can do it in an extension:

Follow the steps on [this tutorial from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/School_tutorial/The_Essentials_of_an_Extension)

Then, when you have that extension working, you replace the sayHello contents with this very simplistic way of doing what you want:

```
var pref = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1'].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
pref.setIntPref("dom.max_script_run_time", 30);
```

This will do what you want.